# Mod Mam archive issue between multiple resources , issue opened in github

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, psi, converse.js

I have two login with different resource for my xmpp account , now i came across a situation wherein if i am login i received all the messages sent/received to both resources , Now one of my resource(desktop) goes offline and if any messages sent to me will be received to resource(mobile) which is online. this goes perfect till this point.

Now when i logged in back to my another resource(desktop) and try to retrieve archive history it is resulting into messages those were sent by me and but not getting messages sent to me .Messages sent are there but received Messages are not there .

Messages those were received by my resource(mobile) which was online , did not return to resource(desktop) .

i tried to implement the same scenario with different client and it is working fine with it . i read the document about resource priority and kept(5) as its value for all my resources too.
I have Ejabberd 15.09 and i also tested it with 15.11

could anyone please suggest me where i am wrong.

[updates have been made to this please check this link.]

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ? Which mod_mam version are you using and how is it configured ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is supposed to work. Message archive for a given resource contains only messages received by that resource. It means that when you are offline, that resource does not receive the messages. You need to check the archive without a specific resource to be able to get the message archive for all your resources.

Comment: hi mickael, thank you for your reply. the message sent has bare jid mentioned and not the full jid. also what we observed is that whenever a message has a subject node it is not retrieved from archive using mam.

Comment: Mssage send to bare JID are delivered to full JID if there is a resource online, so my comment is still valid.

Comment: Please, note that this is normal that message of type headline or groupchat are not stored on user MAM archive. This is by design.

Comment: i am not trying to retrieve muc or headline messages . there is one thing causing it is subject tag , if i add the subject tag i am not getting messages  from archive . if messages are without subject tag it is returned from archive .

Comment: But do you have a body or just a subject ? Only messages with body are stored, as described in spec. Do you have a full XMPP packet as exemple ?

Comment: Message xml  format i we are using :<message to='123456789@xyz.myapp.com' from='987654321@xyz.myapp.com' type='chat' chat_sent='2015-12-01T11:42:14.903Z' xmlns='jabber:client' id='p-235209083'><body>prasad666</body><subject>text</subject><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>